# jvmti : jni getobjectclass and sometimes getintfieldcrashes crashes

Tags: crash, segmentation-fault, jvmti, jnienv

I am writing a jvmti agent for java programs.I am trying to read objects on the stack.Using jnienv pointer received on VMinit/vmstart event.
I succeeded in reading objects upon methodexit event using the foll:
get varaible (slot) from getlocalvariableentry() ; 
from the variable signature use jni functions to get object, use getlocalobject function for a reference object/subclass of object.Then if its a subclass of object; jni::getobjectclass(); use returned class and obtain fields in the class;
using getclassfields(); then get field signature from getfieldname();  then call appropriate function for the field as per its signature eg getintfield() for int field.
Howver once I try this upon Objects created within a try block within the function for which methodexit event is raised; I get a crash(SIGSEGV) everytime at Getobjectclass() .Is this because the object has gotten destroyed being out of scope; If so how to read values of variables in a try block of a function at function exit.
obtain crash when upon reading a jobject for Integer (from localvariabletableentry) object , I call getintfield() for its int field member MIN_VALUE which is its first member.If I just try to read member "value" of Integer class then  calling getintfield() does not crash.
Is this crash because Im trying to read a static final member of a class ie. member MIN_VALUE Of integer class.
How to come around this and avoid the crashes?

Comment: 1) How to know if a jobject gotten via GetLocalobject is destroyed already or not?

Comment: 2) How to know if a field of a class(obtained via Getclassfields) is a static or final member of its class

Comment: 3) the getobjectclass crashes when jobject refers to a class object which is empty (has no members) and is in a try block within the function upon whose exit getobjectclass is called